# Delete all the rows which corresponds to the user_id

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have the table with columns:
tags_id | tags    | user_id
1       |android  | 7
2       |windows  | 7
3       |windows  | 2
4       |mac      | 7
5       |windows  | 1
6       |windows  | 3

like this what i want to do is delete all the the rows with user_id=7.
here 'tags_id'is auto_increment , tags are returned from the user and user_id is also from the user profile.
But i get no changes from the code below.

Here is my PHP Code:

```
<?php 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    //Getting values
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];


    //Creating an sql query
            $sql = "DELETE FROM user_tags WHERE user_id = '$user_id'";


    //Importing our db connection script
    require_once('dbConnect.php');

    //Executing query to database
    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        echo 'Tags updated';
    }else{
        echo 'Tags could not be update';
    }

    //Closing the database 
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Comment: Check this out. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_delete.asp

Answer (score 2):

Because the name of the user field, it is wrong. You ve used users_id instead of user_id.See below:

Before:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM user_tags WHERE users_id = '$user_id'";
```

After:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM user_tags WHERE user_id = '$user_id'";
```

One more hint: Use prepared statement. See the link here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: Still not working after the changes also

Answer (score 2):

Use always prepared statement for prevent injection

```
<?php
require_once('dbConnect.php');

$delete_user_tags = $con->prepare(" DELETE from user_tags WHERE user_id = ? ");
$delete_user_tags->bind_param("i", $user_id);

if (isset($_POST['user_id'];)) {
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
    if (!$delete_user_tags->execute()) {
        echo ('Tags could not be update');
    } else {
        echo ('Tags updated!');
    }

}
```

Comment: your code perfectly for me thank you , Now all the tags corresponding to user_id is deleted so what i must do to insert the fresh set of tags to the same user_id... i used this code:                                                $sql = "INSERT INTO user_tags (tags,user_id) VALUES ('$tags','$user_id')";  .

Comment: please accept the answer. Same as the code you have to use prepared statemnt. than I don't know your code of insert.. I think are an array of tags.